# Search multiple words in Twint Python Library

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter, twint

I would like to search for multiple words using the Twint Python Library. However, I can only find guidance on searching for one word within tweets. So, for example, "twint -s "pregnant" --since "2020-03-01 13:13:59" -o "sample.csv" --csv" gathers tweets that contain the word pregnant. When I add ...-s "pregnant -s "COVID," the code runs, but gathers tweets containing the word pregnant or COVID. How do I search for multiple words? Even better would be the ability to search multiple words using and/or.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this issue on Twint page on Github [link](https://github.com/twintproject/twint/issues/165). Also, this [link](https://github.com/twintproject/twint/issues/222) may be helpful.

According to the explanations in the above link from the 3 samples below:

Sample 1: "king a none burger" 
Sample 2: "king a none" 
Sample 3: "burger king none"

`twint -s "king burger"`  gathers sample 1 and 3 
`twint -s "king OR burger"`  gathers sample 1, 2, and 3 
`twint -s "\"burger king\""`  gathers just sample 3

Answer (score -1):

There are probably more elegant ways of doing this, but grep actually works.